# Intersection of two text files

Tags: python, text

I have 2 different text files such as:

```
    text1 = Movie1 interact comedi seri featur ...
            Movie2 each week audienc write ...
            Movie3 struggl make success relationship ....

    text2 = Movie2 Action
            Movie3 Drama
            Movie4 Sci-fi
```

What I want is

```
    text3 = Movie2 each week audienc write ...
            Movie3 struggl make success relationship ....
and text4 = Movie2 Action
            Movie3 Drama
```

text1 and text2 are just illustrative, they are bigger than these. text1 includes many movies' summaries, text2 includes much more movies' genre information. I want to extract only 10000 intersections of them according to only movie name into text3 and text4. How can I do that in Python when considered I am new to it.

Comment: It's fine that you are new to Python, but please show your attempts at the problem first and [edit] your question when you have tried something

Comment: Essentially, you want to get lines where the first word exists in both files, is that it?

Comment: Exactly Pedro. I tried to do it line by line for each of them but it takes forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have each text file open already:

```
def process_file(f):
    return list(filter(lambda l: l.strip(), f.readlines())) # remove blank lines

def get_word(string): # try to get the first word of each line
    try:
        s = string.split(' ')
        return s[0], string
    except:
        return None, string

def insert_line(string, dict):    # insert the line into a dict
    word, line = get_word(string) # with the first word as key
    if word:
        dict[word] = line

lines1 = process_file(file1)
lines2 = process_file(file2)
dict1 = {}
for line in lines1:
    insert_line(line, dict1)
dict2 = {}
for line in lines2:
    insert_line(line, dict2) # build dicts
set1 = set(dict1.keys())     # build sets with keys
set2 = set(dict2.keys())
intersection = set1 & set2   # get set intersection
intersection_lines = []
for key in intersection:     # build list with intersection
    intersection_lines.append(dict1[key])
```

At the end of this script, `intersection_lines` will contain the lines you want from file1. To do the same for file2, you just exchange `dict1` for `dict2`. This works this simply because the intersection operation is already implemented in the `set` class as the `&` operator. Note that this only works if the first word of each line is unique.